Specify the type of a C++ pointer at runtime (generic pointer)
I am developing a simulation code written entirely in C++ where we use double precision for all computations. Now I want to make it configurable to use single precision if the user wants. The problem is that all our matrices are defined as double so I am wondering if I can have a generic pointer and specify the type at runtime. For instance, let's say our code looks like this:
double *mat = nullptr;
mat = new double[some_size];
// Some operations...
delete[] mat;

No I want to use same variable and not introduce a new one for single precision since this will require lots of modifications in the code. I tried void pointer but the problem is that I cannot use indices to access elements in the matrix:
void *ptr = nullptr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ptr = new complex<double>[10];

for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  ptr[i].real(1.33445);
  ptr[i].imag(443.223);
}

delete[] ptr;

In this case I get the following error:
error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'void'
Also I get a warning which says that the void pointer cannot be deleted.
Now my question is:
Is there any possible way (similar to a void pointer) to have a generic pointer and then cast it properly to a specific type at runtime?

A volid* is just that - void means nothing, so it cannot be used to point to a proper type. And if you used a pointer to single to access a matrix of doubles you would just get garbage as the offsets would all be incorrect.

It feels like the job for a union, but I assume that would mean lots of changes as well. But casting pointers all over the place will make the code brittle and hard to maintain.

Using templates for the data type is the obvious solution.

Do not tag C for C++ questions.

C++ templates are discussed in any good C++ book and/or tutorial.  How do things like std::vector, std::list, etc. work with different types?  Even looking at your code, you have complex<double> -- how does that work, where you specify that complex uses double?  Templates.

@EricPostpischil The question is valid for C language as well.

@Dan The question is valid for C language as well -- The code in your question uses new and delete, so it is not C.  Second, C++ has ways to deal with this issue that C does not have.

If you want an answer that is applicable to insert language here, please ask a separate question and tag is with the insert language here language tag. Only use more than one language tag for questions that deal with programs written in more than one language, or ask about a specific difference between languages. This is the convention for this site (as I understand it).

Short answer:  no.   A consequence of storing a non-void pointer (in your first sample case, a double *) into a void * is losing all type information.     Furthermore, to use the void * as if it points to something else, it is necessary to convert the pointer back  to the correct type e.g.  double *dptr = (double *)ptr;  *dptr = 42.0; is correct in your first case, but float *fptr = (float *)ptr; *fptr = 42.0f; (or conversion to ANY type other than double * and dereferencing) gives UNDEFINED behaviour.  This is, essentially, the same in both C and C++.

IMO it would be more advantageous to templatize your matrix code by specifying T as the template parameter, and then from there devise a way to choose T at runtime and work from there (there are various ways to do this).  Using void * and trying to jump through all of the these hoops that others have mentioned (for example, undefined behavior) is a losing effort.

@Dan: Even if the question were valid for C, that does not mean answers would be. Answers might use specific features of a language. And that is a problem for Stack Overflow, because it is not here just for you. It is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers for other people in the future. Somebody will search Stack Overflow using the C tag, and we do not want their search results muddled with unhelpful C++ answers. Policy on both the C and C++ tags is not to combine them absent reasons such as asking about interactions or differences between the languages.

Your "some operations" of your code change if your type is a double* versus a complex<double>*, since a double does not have a .real and .imag.  Template programming can get you only so far, but then the differences in the types would have to be handled by either data type abstraction or template specialization.

would something along std::variant<double, float> number fit ? (c++17 .... )

Thanks everyone to put your valuable time on this issue. The solution that @Chukwujiobi Canon posted solved my problem. So, I will create a void pointer and then cast to the correct type whenever I need to pass the matrix to the relevant function in LAPACK for the correct type.

A void* is not meant to be used that way. The only good use of a void* is in low level code where we need to pass along the address of a memory location.
If you must access the object lying at that memory location like in your use of the subscript operator, you must explicitly convert this void* to a T* where T is a complete type.
This means that you will be doing a whole lot of explicit conversions which is unsafe if you happen to convert to the wrong type. Anyways here is one possible approach:
void* ptr = nullptr;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ptr = new complex<double>[10];

for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  static_cast<complex<double>*>(ptr)[i].real(1.33445);
  static_cast<complex<double>*>(ptr)[i].imag(443.223);
}

delete[] static_cast<complex<double>*>(ptr);

Thanks a lot for your kind help! This code solved my problem. I need to pass the void pointer to LAPACK and BLAS functions and with your solution I can cast the pointer according to the function.
